# how to write commands to perform before my application installed or after app is uninstalled?

Tags: android, installation

I have developed an app, and I want to check the status of the" Allow Installation of Non-Market Apps" option (enabled/disabled). I want to prevent my app from being installed if that option is Enabled!
So how to write commands that will execute in the installation process, and how May I do the same but In the Un-installation process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to execute any code before your app is installed or after your app in uninstalled. In fact, when your app is installed, it is in a stopped state and none of its components can be started until the user explicitly starts the app himself. Likewise, once the app is uninstalled, there are no app components left that can run any code.

The best you can do is check the state of that setting on the first launch of the app, or do it each time your Application is created. Set a boolean in SharedPreferences and disable whatever app functions based on that.